# Degrees of freedom for likelihood ratio test help

Tags: self-study, econometrics, likelihood-ratio, degrees-of-freedom

I have estimated a probit model & now I would like to test it. I have calculated the likelihood ratio test but now I am having trouble working out what the 'degrees of freedom is' to determine whether I reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.

I have done some googling and found that the degree of freedom should be n-1. Is that correct? For background my model is as follows:

Pr(lfp) = c + k5 + k618 + age + wc + hc + inc

And my restricted model is:

Pr(lfp) = c + k5  + age + wc + inc

Thanks all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you're talking about the degrees of freedom when performing asymptotic chi-squared test that arises under [Wilk's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test#Distribution:_Wilks.E2.80.99_theorem).

As it says at the Wikipedia article there,

> the test statistic ${\displaystyle -2\log(\Lambda )}$ for a nested model will be asymptotically chi-squared distributed ${\displaystyle \chi ^{2}}$ with degrees of freedom equal to the difference in dimensionality of $Θ$ and ${\displaystyle \Theta_{0}}$, when $H_{0}$ holds true

That is, *if the models are nested*, it's the difference in the number of free parameters under the two models.